# Creating map of Africa using d3.js and topoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, topojson

i want to create map of Africa using d3.js and topoJSON. I have that datasource https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bricedev/3905007f1794b0cb0bcd/raw/ad5c995f6990f7c3c7fad5c6206bc6fd5462f1fb/africa.json

That is my code. How i can get properties and create correct map? Please help me where is the error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="D3byEX 12.15" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var width = 1000, height = 728;


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr({ width: width, height: height });
    var mainGroup = svg.append("g");
    mainGroup.style({ stroke: "white", "stroke-width": "2px", "stroke-opacity": 0.0 });

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bricedev/3905007f1794b0cb0bcd/raw/ad5c995f6990f7c3c7fad5c6206bc6fd5462f1fb/africa.json';
    d3.json(url, function (error, africa) {
        var countries = topojson.feature(africa, africa.objects.countries).features;
        var neighbors = topojson.neighbors(africa.objects.countries.geometries);

        var color = d3.scale.category20();
        mainGroup.selectAll("path", "countries")
            .data(countries)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(d.color = d3.max(neighbors[i],
                    function (n) { return countries[n].color; }) + 1 | 0);
            });

        mainGroup.selectAll("path")
            .on("mouseover", function () {
                console.log("mouseover");
                d3.select(this).style("stroke-opacity", 1.0);
            });
        mainGroup.selectAll("path")
            .on("mouseout", function () {
                d3.select(this).style("stroke-opacity", 0.0);
            });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topojson is not in WGS84, that is to say lat/long coordinate space or unprojected data. D3.projection() requires WGS84.

Your topojson is already projected in, what I assume is, the [Africa Lambert Conformal Conic](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/africa-lambert-conformal-conic/) projection. You do not need to use a projection to display this in d3.js. In order to display this data without a projection you can define the projection of your geoPath as:

```
path = d3.geoPath().projection(null);
```

This is how the topojson was projected in [the block](http://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/3905007f1794b0cb0bcd) in which that data came from.

If you need to scale or translate the projection, then d3.geoTransform can help you, see [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5663666).

Alternatively, you can reproject your topojson so that it uses lat/long pairs and will properly project using d3.projection().