# How can I find out what projection my pre-projected GeoJSON is using?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, map-projections

My question is very similar to [D3 V4 Properly placing a bubble in the US Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035696/d3-v4-properly-placing-a-bubble-in-the-us-map), but the map I'm using is a map of Scotland's local authority districts instead so I can't quite see how to apply either of the solutions.

I'm creating a bubble map on top of a choropleth map of Scotland, with circles at specified locations which I'm providing as latitude/longitude coordinates.

However, the locations of the circles are completely out - the circle for Aberdeen is in the sea!

Based on [D3 V4 Properly placing a bubble in the US Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035696/d3-v4-properly-placing-a-bubble-in-the-us-map), I think perhaps the GeoJSON is pre-projected so I'm using two different projections, one for the map and one for the circles. Ideally I think I would find a different GeoJSON that didn't cause this problem, but I think the one I'm using from https://martinjc.github.io/UK-GeoJSON/ is the only one available.

So my question is, is there a sensible method for figuring out what projection this map is, in order that I can use the same projection for the circles?

```js
var year = 2015;
var measurement = "tonnage";

drawMap(year, measurement)

function drawMap(year, measurement) {

  // Convert the year and measurement to a concatenated string
  var yearString = year.toString();
  var measurementString = measurement.toString();
  var option = measurementString.concat(yearString);

  // The svg
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  // Map and projection
  var path = d3.geoPath();
  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([-4.1826, 56.8169])
    .scale(1400)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
  //  .scale(20*width / Math.PI)
  //  .translate([width / 2 + 150, height / 2 +2670]);

  // Data and color scale
  var data = {};
  if (measurement === "tonnage") {
    var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
      .domain([0, 50, 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 20000])
      .range(d3.schemeBlues[7]);
  } else {
    var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
      .domain([0, 1000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 9000, 10000])
      .range(d3.schemeReds[7]);
  }

  // Load external data and boot
  d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squirrel-star/scotland/main/geojsonscotlandladjson.geojson")
    .defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squirrel-star/scotland/main/fishperLA.csv", function(d) {
      data[d.code] = +d[option];
    })
    .await(ready);

  svg.selectAll("*").remove();

  function ready(error, topo) {


    // Adding the bubbles in

    var markers = [{
        long: 2.0943,
        lat: 57.1497
      }, // Aberdeen
      {
        long: 2.7005,
        lat: 56.2230
      }, // Anstruther
      {
        long: 4.6292,
        lat: 55.4586
      }, // Ayr
    ];

    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topo.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      // draw each country
      .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection)
      )
      // set the color of each country
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        d.total = data[d.properties.LAD13NM] || 0;
        return colorScale(d.total);
      })
    <!-- // Add circles:   -->
    svg
      .selectAll("myCircles")
      .data(markers)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0]
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1]
      })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", "69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("fill-opacity", .4);

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<svg id="myMap" width="400" height="400"></svg>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some bad news for you, the actual reason the points are wrong is that you're missing a minus sign in front of the latitude. Ayr has a latitude of [-4.6](https://latitude.to/map/gb/united-kingdom/cities/ayr), not 4.6. Just adding a `-` in front of the points fixed it for me.

```js
var year = 2015;
var measurement = "tonnage";

drawMap(year, measurement)

function drawMap(year, measurement) {

  // Convert the year and measurement to a concatenated string
  var yearString = year.toString();
  var measurementString = measurement.toString();
  var option = measurementString.concat(yearString);

  // The svg
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  // Map and projection
  var path = d3.geoPath();
  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([-4.1826, 56.8169])
    .scale(1400)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
  //  .scale(20*width / Math.PI)
  //  .translate([width / 2 + 150, height / 2 +2670]);

  // Data and color scale
  var data = {};
  if (measurement === "tonnage") {
    var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
      .domain([0, 50, 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 20000])
      .range(d3.schemeBlues[7]);
  } else {
    var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
      .domain([0, 1000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 9000, 10000])
      .range(d3.schemeReds[7]);
  }

  // Load external data and boot
  d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squirrel-star/scotland/main/geojsonscotlandladjson.geojson")
    .defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squirrel-star/scotland/main/fishperLA.csv", function(d) {
      data[d.code] = +d[option];
    })
    .await(ready);

  svg.selectAll("*").remove();

  function ready(error, topo) {
    // Adding the bubbles in

    var markers = [{
        long: -2.0943,
        lat: 57.1497
      }, // Aberdeen
      {
        long: -2.7005,
        lat: 56.2230
      }, // Anstruther
      {
        long: -4.6292,
        lat: 55.4586
      }, // Ayr
    ];

    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topo.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      // draw each country
      .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection)
      )
      // set the color of each country
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        d.total = data[d.properties.LAD13NM] || 0;
        return colorScale(d.total);
      })
    <!-- // Add circles:   -->
    svg
      .selectAll("myCircles")
      .data(markers)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0]
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1]
      })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", "69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("fill-opacity", .4);

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<svg id="myMap" width="400" height="400"></svg>
```

Comment: That's the best news I've had all day! Time to actually learn how geography works, I think!