# D3js Setting projection on geoPath() breaks map

Tags: d3.js, maps, geojson

I am trying to make a map of North Carolina, USA. Everything is working until I change

`var path = d3.geoPath();`

to

`var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);`

When I do that, the map turn into this triangle off the top right corner.

Block: http://bl.ocks.org/Ognami/0ce1d2777c97f4adedfd06e32996076a

Comment: Your data would appear to be projected based on the name `nc-albers`, which can be confirmed when looking at the coordinates, eg: `[870.3929659530004,229.4677310032339]` as these aren't latitude longitude pairs. This also explains why it works without a projection - it's already Cartesian data. A d3 geoprojection takes in lat/long pairs - non Cartesian data (points on a 3d globe). Instead, a d3.geoIdentity would probably fit the bill fairly easily. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430876/7106086) should help with working with projected data and/or d3 geoIdentities.

Comment: Oh.... Somehow this very important tidbit just didn't process in my head. I understand now. The coordinate I am trying to plot is lat/log, but the map is already projected to flat coords for my map. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, it's easy to miss. Glad to help.