# How can I scale my map to fit my svg size with d3 and geojson path data

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

I am trying to create a d3 SVG that draws a map of New York State and scale it so that it fits the size of my SVG, the issue I am having is that when I use `.fitSize([height, width], mapObject)` it only returns a `NaN` error in the console.

the [topoJSON file of NYS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/us-states/NY-36-new-york-counties.json) I am using

I am able to get the map to display without scaling but of course, it is not optimized and needs to be scaled

I have attempted what is said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430361/scaling-d3-v4-map-to-fit-svg-or-at-all) but I have not figured out the correct solution

```
var map = d3.json('./ny.json')

Promise.all([map]).then(data => {
  var height = 800;
  var width  = 800;
  var mapData = data[0]

  // original geoJSON to that works without scaling 
  // var geoData = topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects["cb_2015_new_york_county_20m"]).features
  //

  var geoData = topojson.feature(mapData, {
    type:"GeometryCollection",
    geometries: mapData.objects["cb_2015_new_york_county_20m"].geometries,
  })

  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
                     .fitSize([width, height], geoData)

  var path = d3.geoPath()
               .projection(projection)

  d3.select('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .selectAll('.county')
      .data(geoData)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
        .classed('.county', true)
        .attr('d', path)

})
```

I am pretty sure this is a formatting error on my part, but I am unsure of what data `.fitSize()` or `.fitExtent()` is trying to compare against.

right now the way the code site I receive no error outputted to the console but I also have no data append to the SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that fitSize takes a geojson *object* while selectAll.data() takes an *array*, you are using one of these two for both in `geoData`. This leaves two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

If we use

```
var geoData = topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects["cb_2015_new_york_county_20m"]).features

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
                 .fitSize([width, height], geoData)
```

We get NaN errors because the projection is not set properly as we aren't passing a geojson object, just an array of geojson objects. We could solve this by making a feature collection with `geoData` and passing that to fitSize:

```
var geoData = topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects["cb_2015_new_york_county_20m"]).features

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
     .fitSize([width, height], {type:"FeatureCollection", features: geoData})
```

Now we are passing a geojson feature collection to fitSize, we're all go on the projection, and since `geoData` is still an array, we can pass that to selectAll.data() unchanged.

[Here's a block.](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/95e202556995db9745dc904a7ccce324)

**Solution 2:**

If we use:

```
var geoData = topojson.feature(mapData, {
  type:"GeometryCollection",
  geometries: mapData.objects["cb_2015_new_york_county_20m"].geometries,
})
```

We get a geojson object, projection.fitSize works, but `selectAll().data(geoData)` doesn't add any features as it isn't an array - the enter selection is empty. We can substitute in `selectAll().data(geoData.features)` to solve this and enter one path per feature (alternatively we could use `.data([geoData])` to enter one feature for all the paths).

[Here's a block.](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/e8fd091741795ca151488130020f51b8)

*Both blocks are drawn at the correct scale - the map exceeds the block bounds as I didn't alter your 800x800 dimensions*