# Struggling to convert .shp to usable .json file

Tags: d3.js, geojson, geo

I'm trying to adapt Mike Bostock's "Let's Make a Map" tutorial (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) to my own dataset of real estate parcels, but when I try to render it I get this:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJDZA.png)

I started with a Shapefile, and turned it into .json by adapating the code in the tutorial:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  parcels.json \
  Parcels_Clipped.shp
```

Then I converted it with this:

```
topojson \
    -o parcels2.json \
    -- \
parcels.json
```

In my d3.js script, I imported it with:

```
queue()
        .defer(d3.json, 'parcel2s.json')
        .await(drawMap);
```

And here's my drawMap() function:

```
function drawMap( error, parcels ) {

    var width = 600,
        height = 600;

    var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .center([0, 40.0092216])
        .rotate([-105.2047471, 0])
        .parallels([39.71666666666667, 40.78333333333333])
        .scale(6000)
     //   .fitSize([600,600]);
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection)
        .pointRadius(2);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

  svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.feature(parcels, parcels.objects.parcels))
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()))
        .attr("class", "parcel");
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, and at least I'm getting *something* as output, but as you can see from the posted image the polygons are all over the place.  They should show real estate parcels.

Comment: I can't see your shape file -  but it is projected (it is not comprised of unprojected, 3D lat long points but rather Cartesian x,y values). D3 geoprojections project unprojected data (they don't re-project already projected data). The prj file should be able to show that the data is projected but can also be used to unproject the data as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430876/7106086) answer for some potential solutions.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks a ton.

Comment: The only thing that's not working is that my map is upside down, and .reflectY(true) makes it disappear completely.  By inspecting elements I can see that the first coordinate value goes from 135 (without inversion) to -280000 (with inversion).  UPDATE: Nevermind, I just had to specify the inversion *before* the fitSize.