# Impossible to display a TopoJson map with Svelte

Tags: d3.js, svelte, topojson

I'm trying to view a TopoJson map with Svelte (and D3), but I can't figure out what's wrong because there is absolutely nothing displayed and yet the console output does not return any errors.
Does anyone have a clue?

**I put below the link of a Svelte repl and the code used :**

https://svelte.dev/repl/1cadb042523d40a5803171b9d29367af?version=3.48.0

```js
<script>
  import { geoAlbers, geoPath, geoAlbersUsa, } from "d3-geo";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import * as topojson from 'topojson-client';
    import { draw } from 'svelte/transition';
  
  const path = geoPath().projection(null);
    let deps = [];
    let mesh;

onMount(async () => {
    const france = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Fralacticus/b6584c5865607300b2b5a0559ae47cbb/raw/8287c28f9a3eab4e3d1aa5f7e6181f064957c9de/deptopo.json'
    ).then(d => d.json());  
    console.log({ france });
    
    deps = topojson.feature(france, france.objects.dep).features;   
    console.log({ deps });
    
    mesh = topojson.mesh(france, france.objects.dep, (a, b) => a !== b);
});
</script>


<svg viewBox="0 0 910 610">
  <g fill="white" stroke="black">
        {#each deps as feature, i}
            <path d={path(feature)} />
        {/each} 
    </g>
</svg>
```

**The map viewer and what it displays (this is the expected result):**

https://mapshaper.org/?files=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Fralacticus/b6584c5865607300b2b5a0559ae47cbb/raw/8287c28f9a3eab4e3d1aa5f7e6181f064957c9de/deptopo.json

[image: Expected map]

Comment: Rather than resizing the viewbox you can use d3.geoIdentity() and fitSize() to automatically scale and center the data when dealing with already projected data like yours ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430876/7106086))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the data, you will see that the values are huge and just do not fit the current dimensions of the SVG. You can e.g. increase the `viewBox` to make the map show up:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10000000 10000000">
  <!-- stroke-width adjusted for large viewBox -->
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1000px" fill="none">
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1449eecd35414151a9229b8c47877643?version=3.48.0)

`france.transform` appears to contain some additional information, but I do not know how that is supposed to be used. You can always calculate the bounding box yourself from the data and there appears to be function for this: [`bbox`](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#bbox).

If the large scale of the data points is maintained, the `stroke-width` needs to be very high (e.g. `1000px`), because it gets scaled down by the `viewBox`.

Comment: Even with your values there is nothing displayed. But thanks, I'll look for an explanation in the json file.

Comment: @Gaiusfr The styling is off, change the fill or adjust stroke

Comment: @Gaiusfr: (At the scale of the data you need something like `stroke-width: 1000px;` to make that actually show up.)

Comment: It works , great !  There are still adjustments to be made, but most of it is done